# Sass Function with list as argument

Tags: function, sass, mixins

I'm trying to create what I find to be a very complex function in sass.

Goal: create various helper classes for padding-top, padding-bottom, padding, margin-top, etc.

I've created a for loop

```
@for $n from 10 through 160
    @if $n % 10 == 0
    .h-padding-#{$n}
        padding: #{$n}px 0

    .h-pt-#{$n}
        padding-top: #{$n}px

    .h-pb-#{$n}
        padding-bottom: #{$n}px
```

To generate the classes, but I now want to add a variation, which will make the number `#{n}` half, on mobile.

Basically:

```
.#{$utility-class-slug}-pb-#{$n}
    padding-bottom: #{$n}px

    +media("<=phone")
        padding-bottom: calc( #{$n}px / 2 )
```

What I'm trying to here, is create a function so I don't have to repeat this `media...` every time.

```
=generateProperty($property, $size...)
    #{$property}: nth($size, 1) + px nth($size, 2) + px
```

Which is called as

`+generateProperty(margin, $n, auto)` in case of `margin: 0 auto`
`+generateProperty(margin-top, $n)` in case of `margin-top: $n`

Altough this is not working and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong, or how to structure it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to modify this a little but I hope it gets you going in the right direction:

```scss
@mixin genProp($prop, $value, $media: null) {
  #{$prop}: #{$value}px;

  @if ($media != null) {
    @media ($media) {
      #{$prop}: #{$value / 2}px;
    }
  }
}

@for $n from 10 through 160 {
    @if ($n % 10 == 0) {
      .h-padding-#{$n} {
        @include genProp('padding', #{$n}px 0);
      }

      .h-pt-#{$n} {
        @include genProp('padding-top', $n, 'max-width: 768px');
      }

      .h-pb-#{$n} {
        @include genProp('padding-bottom', $n, 'max-width: 768px');
      }
    }
}
```